# How to require users to set their role_session_name with scp

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-policies, aws-organizations

Using scp, I would like to require role_session_name to users who assume roles in my organization accounts when running terraform template. The `role_session_name` value need to be equals to their iam `username`.
I have attached below scp in my organization

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "sts:RoleSessionName": [
            "${aws:username}"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Below the `~/.aws/config` file content

```
[profile my_profile]
region = us-west-3
role_arn = arn:aws:iam:ACOUNT_ID:role/role_name
output = json
```

below `provider` section of terraform template

```
provider "aws" {
  shared_credentials = "~/.aws/credentials"
  region  = "eu-west-3"
  profile = "my_profile"
}
```

Without specifying `role_session_name` = my_aws_user_name` inside the config file, I am able to run the template without being blocked by the scp.

How to achieve this please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT

I finally setup an AWS organization to test. The SCP as you now have is working fine. Role is in account A. SCP attached to account B:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "sts:RoleSessionName": [
            "${aws:username}"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Using a user in account B, I tried to assume a Role in Account A using a random session name. Got access denied.

```
>aws sts assume-role --profile accountB --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<account-A>:role/<rolename> --role-session-name abc

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::<account-B>:user/<username> is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<account-A>:role/<rolename>
```

But when I use a session name that is same as my username, I am able to.

```
>aws sts assume-role --profile accountB --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<account-A>:role/<rolename> --role-session-name username

{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "xxx",
        "SecretAccessKey": "xxx",
        "SessionToken": "xxx",
        "Expiration": "2022-03-23T10:31:52Z"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "xxx:username",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/xxx/yyy"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Register Sole for your answer but even after changing `StringEquals` to `StringLike` . I still can assume role and create resources without setting `role_session_name`

Comment: @Jean-PascalMEWENEMESSE I see.. Unfortunately I don't have a setup to test. If you remove the `aws:PrincipalArn` condition altogether, can you confirm if this time it works? It would block most requests, but at least this is to verify the other condition is working. If it works, I think it is better to specify the action `sts:AssumeRole` to limit the deny to only Assume Role requests.

Comment: If I remove the `aws:PrincipalArn` condition, it will sur block. But it also block iam users with management console access. I only want programmically users who make assume role api call. To avoid that, I added `sts:AssumeRole` action but still, it pass without `role_session_name`

Comment: Just checking, you attach this policy to the account where the users are, right? Not the account where the roles are.

Comment: @Jean-PascalMEWENEMESSE Anyway I edited the answer. The policy that you now have in the question works. The only thing I can think of is ensure you attach it to the account where the users are. See my answer for working example.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really appreciate @Register Sole . You are right your answer is correct regarding the previous description of the problem. I have edited the question to be more specific about my issue and add additional details. Thank a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243233/discussion-between-jean-pascal-mewenemesse-and-register-sole).

Comment: @Jean-PascalMEWENEMESSE Yup better to chat. I don't see you in the chat room though, not sure if you get the message.

Answer (score 0):

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam:::user/ is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam:::role/T
this issue is your profile account doesnt has permission attach policy for other account, so I give the IAM full access of role then run fine.